# What variations are allowed to a "European cv" template (if I want it to be still legitimately called a "European CV")?

Tags: resume, job-search, career-development, europe, europass

In order to apply for a certain position, I need to submit a "European CV". ([this](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/sites/default/files/europass_cv_instructions_en.pdf))

Assuming that I keep the "style" (font, formatting, etc.), what variations am I allowed to do (if I want it to be still legitimately called a "European CV")? For example, am I allowed to switch sections around, add new ones (instead of lumping them together under "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION", delete some sections, etc?

Comment: Note that the document you are referring to says "Europass CV", not "European CV". This page has a lot of examples, as you can see they they have quite a bit of variation: http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/documents/curriculum-vitae/examples

Answer (score 3):

The choice of font and formatting is largely irrelevant (just make sure that it's clear, legible, and contains correct spelling, obviously).

It's the headings and content that are important here.  You can change things around, but make sure that it's relevant for the role that you're applying for.

As with any resume/CV, the key thing is to communicate your fitness for the role in question in terms of your skillset, qualifications, and experience.

Also important is how you communicate these facts.  If the CV is confusing, you won't be interviewed....